# python tkinter ttk styles

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Normally, when I use the TTk styles, I define a style object by object. If I had many forms and windows I define a `setStyle()` method to do that. But, in this new application make sense to have just a `setStyle()` method in the App main class. The problem is that it ignores the settings in the `App.setStyle()` method. Any suggestion?

```
    class App(Tk):
...
    def setStyles(self):
        self.s = ttk.Style()
        self.s.theme_use('alt')
        padding = "12 12 12 12"
        self.s.configure('frmWin.TFrame', padding=padding)
        self.s.configure('big.TButton', font=(None, 24, "bold"))
        self.s.configure('TLabel', font=(None, 28), anchor=W, justify=LEFT, sticky=W)
        self.s.configure('TLabelframe', borderwidth=40, bordercolr="blue", labelmargins=(40,0))
        self.s.configure('TLabelframe.Label', font=(None, 20), sticky=W)

        # [MM] formNewPlayer
        self.s.configure("frmNewPlayer.Treeview", rowheight=72, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 24,'bold')) # Modify the font of the body
        self.s.configure("frmNewPlayer.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
        self.s.configure("frmNewPlayer.TLabel", font=("Calibri", 16))
        self.s.configure("frmNewPlayer.Tentry", font=("Calibri", 22), width=16)
        self.s.configure('frmNewPlayer.TButton', font=("Calibri", 24, "bold"))
        
        # [MM] AskDialog
        self.s.configure("AskDlg.TButton",foreground="black",
                                         background="white",
                                         width=4,
                                         padding=[10, 10, 10, 10],
                                         font = "Verdana 48 bold")
        self.s.configure("AskDlg.TLabel", foreground="black",
                                         background="white",
                                         image="",
                                         padding=[50, 50, 50, 50],
                                         font = "Verdana 48")
        self.s.configure("AskDlg.TFrame", foreground="black",
                                         background="white",
                                         borderwidth = 8,
                                         font = "Verdana 48 underline")
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include a small [mcve] that illustrates what you've tried and illustrates the problems you're encountering?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you may check:

- First you have to make sure that you called the settings file correctly, and you imported it. (for `import settings`, you call the class like this: `settings.setStyle()`, and for `from settings import setStyle` you simply call it with `setStyle()`);
- The second thing is that you probably forgot to call the `setStyle()` class;
- And the third thing may be that you didn't gave the arguments correctly.

If you checked everything and it's still not working, please message me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, thanks for the help. I found the bug, if some debug options are set to True the call to `setStyles()` in `App __init__()` is bypassed. It was a wrong implementation of a complex debug field of flags... everyting works as expected now.